# map file in to the ram

Tags: c++, c, linux, mmap

Platofrm - Linux, Arch - ARM 
Programming lang - C/C++

Objective - map a regular (let say text) file to a pre-known location (physical address) in ram and pass that physical address to some other application. Size of the block which i map at a time is 128K.

The way I am trying to go about is- 
User space process issues the ioctl call to ask a device driver to get a chunk of memory (ram), calculated the physical address and return it to the user space.

User space process needs to maps the file to that physical address space
**I am not sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated.** ???

Issue with mmap call on the file and then calculating the physical address is that, pages are not in memory till someone access them and physical memory pages allocated might not be contiguous.

The other process which will actually access the file is from third party vendor application. That application demands once we pass it the physical address, file contents needs to be present in contiguous memory.

**How i am doing it right now** --

User process call the mmap to device.
Device driver does a kmalloc, calculate the starting physical address and mmap the VMA to that physical address. 
Now user process do a read on the file and copies it to the address space obtained during the mmap.

Issue - Copy of the file exist two location in the ram, one when read is done from disk and other when i copy it to the buffer obtained using mmap and corresponding copying overheads.
In a ideal world i would like to load the file directly from the disk to a known/predefined location.

Comment: Trying to rephrase the question: For a device (embedded Linux?) there is a hardcoded physical address range for IO. This address range should be mapped to a file, so anyone reading or writing the file will doing IO for the device. How can an address range be mapped to a file?

Answer (score 1):

"Mapping a file" implies using virtual addresses rather than physical, so that's not going to do what you want.

If you want to put the file contents into a contiguous block of physical memory, just use `open()` and `read()` once you have obtained the contiguous buffer.

Comment: Yes, u r right. I am doing it the same way as you have suggested. The only issue with that is, the copy of the file exists in the ram at two different places at the same time and also the all the extra copying overhead etc.. I am trying to load the file read from the disk directly in to a preknown locations(physical memory), to avoid extra copy of the file in physical memory and corresponding overhead.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the buffer address returned by `mmap` to `read`, so it gets read straight to there?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like [`madvise()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) with `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` advice argument could help?

Some things to consider:

- How large is the file you're going to be mapping?
- That might affect your ability to get a contiguous block of RAM, even if you were to take the kernel driver based approach.
- For a kernel driver based approach, well behaved drivers typically should not `kmalloc()`, *e.g.* to get a contiguous block of memory, more than 32KB.  Furthermore, you typically can't `kmalloc()` more than 2MB (I've tried this :)).  Is that going to be suitable for your needs?
- If you need a really large chunk of memory something like the kernel's `alloc_bootmem()` function could help, but it only works for static "*built-in*" drivers, not dynamically loadable ones.
- Is there any way you can rework your design so that a large contiguous block of mapped memory isn't necessary?

Comment: Yes.. good point, i never mentioned the size of the block i am trying to map. I am not going to go over 128K. My kernel driver approach works fine presently. I have edited my question to say how i am doing right now and why it is not a perfect solution. 
madvise looks interesting to find about, i was not aware of this.